Chromecast - how update meta data for Flutter?
I use plugin Cast to broadcast Internet radio from a mobile device to Chromecast.
I use this plugin to broadcast Internet radio from a device to Chromecast device.
it generally works. But there's a issue - I can't update the track info without restarting the stream. For example, one track ended - another one started. My application has this information, but I don't know how to correctly transfer it to Chromecast.
The plugin I use supports messages.
I try the following scenario - get mediaSessionId - then pass the following message:
    final message = {
    'type': 'EDIT_TRACKS_INFO',
    'mediaSessionId': _mediaSessionId,
    'tracks': [
      {
        'trackId': _trackId,
        'type': 'AUDIO',
        'trackContentType': 'audio/mp3',
        'name': 'New track',
        'language': 'en',
        'customData': {
          'artist': 'New artist',
          'albumName': 'New album',
          'images': [
            {
              'url': _tmpImage,
            },
          ],
        },
      },
    ],
  };

  _session!.sendMessage(CastSession.kNamespaceMedia, message);

But it doesn't work. I get answer:
 receive message: {requestId: 9, type: INVALID_REQUEST, reason: INVALID_MEDIA_SESSION_ID}

Looks like I still need to get trackId. I am trying to use the following message
final message = {
    'type': 'QUEUE_GET_ITEM',
    'itemId': itemId,
   };

but it doesn't work yet. also the logic is quite confusing - and I'm not sure I'm on the right way.
the plugin supports the following constants - but I can't find in the documentation how to apply it correctly:
static const kNamespaceConnection = 'urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.tp.connection';
static const kNamespaceHeartbeat = 'urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.tp.heartbeat';
static const kNamespaceReceiver = 'urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.receiver';
static const kNamespaceDeviceauth = 'urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.tp.deviceauth';
static const kNamespaceMedia = 'urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.media';

any advice - I will be very grateful

The EDIT_TRACKS_INFO message requires a valid trackId to identify the specific track you want to update information for. You're currently missing this information as hardcoded "1" is being used.
